# Stuck in infinite loop of unmet dependencies due to broken packages

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, dependencies, ros

I posted this question in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50363704/1175065) but found no suggestion. Hence I am posting it here for the hope. This question may appear duplicate of others however, I have tried their solutions but couldn't get any success. I recently removed ROS Indigo using the following command-

```
ravi@lab:~$ sudo apt-get remove ros-*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
```

Now, I needed it. So I tried installing it again using the following command-

```
ravi@lab:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Unfortunately, the above didn't work. So I tried installing dependencies but got no success-

```
ravi@lab:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
ravi@lab:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
ravi@lab:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
```

I tried installing the dependency `ros-indigo-perception` manually but no chance-

```
ravi@lab:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-perception
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-perception : Depends: ros-indigo-perception-pcl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried more and thought of installing another dependency `ros-indigo-perception-pcl` but got in vain-

```
ravi@lab:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-perception-pcl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-perception-pcl : Depends: ros-indigo-pcl-conversions but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-indigo-pcl-ros but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Still trying without any success -

```
ravi@lab:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-pcl-conversions
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-pcl-conversions : Depends: libpcl-1.7-all but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libpcl-1.7-all-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ravi@lab:~$ sudo apt-get install libpcl-1.7-all
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpcl-1.7-all : Depends: libpcl-1.7-all-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ravi@lab:~$ sudo apt-get install libpcl-1.7-all-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpcl-1.7-all-dev : Depends: libpcl-apps-1.7-dev but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libpcl-io-1.7-dev but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libpcl-outofcore-1.7-dev but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libpcl-people-1.7-dev but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libpcl-recognition-1.7-dev but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**My objective is to install ROS Indigo on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS PC** (without reinstalling OS :D )

Any workaround, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it finally. I had to dig more into it and I finally realized that the problem is occurring due to `libusb`.

In order to fix this issue, I first removed `libusb` (sorry, I didn't remember exact version at present). After that, I run `apt-get autoclean`. Then `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` just to make sure everything is at the correct place.

Finally, I used `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full` and it worked.

### Note

After restarting PC, the login doesn't work and it says `Failed to start sesssion`. Don't panic, during the login screen press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. It will take you to the terminal. Use your username and password to login. Finally restore the desktop using following command `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

and after

```
sudo apt install -f
```

or you can try

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

There is some chance the update helps you to fix your dependencies issues

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I used `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade` then `sudo apt install -f` then `sudo apt-get autoremove` and finally `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full`. Unfortunately, it didn't work. Please see the output reported at terminal [here](https://pastebin.com/jnBLyqYc). Please note that `sudo apt upgrade` installed some packages and later `sudo apt autoremove` removed some packages but `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full` still shows the error.

Comment: `sudo apt update` didn't had output or it just because you don't copy & paste it? Besides that, I don't have other solutions

Comment: `sudo apt update` returned very long output. I didn't copy paste it.

Comment: have you used a tutorial to make your installation? you can see [ http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu ] and try a `sudo apt remove` of all package say at "1.4 Installation", in the blue section

Comment: Yes. I have installed ROS Indigo many times on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. However this is the first time I removed it and tried installing again!

Comment: I can't help you more

Comment: I am wondering what went wrong! I really can't think of reinstalling the OS! Anyway I appreciate your kind support! Thank you very much.